# when condition not being evaluated with include statement

Tags: variables, include, ansible, prompt

I have a `tikitaka3.yml` (main yml file) and a `tikitaka3a.yml` (playbook to be included).

I prompt the user for a variable, and then in the tasks section I call it, like so:

```
---
- hosts: all

vars:
  khan:
# contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/imran/Desktop/tobefetched/file1.txt') }}"

vars_prompt:
 - name: targetenv
   prompt: 1.)EPC 2.)CLIENTS 3)TESTERS
   private: False
   default: "1"

gather_facts: no
tasks:

- name: Inlude playbook tikitaka3a
include: /home/khan/Desktop/playbooks/tikitaka3a.yml target=umar
when: targetenv.stdout|int < 2  #this statement has no effect
#when: targetenv == 1  #Neither does this statement
#when: targetenc == "1"  #and neither does this statement have affect


#- name: stuff n stuff # This task will give an error if not commented 
#  debug: var=targetenv.stdout
```

The include statement always comes into affect, without the when condition ever being evaluated.

Why is this happening?

Comment: First of all you should format your code. The right statement is: `when: targetenv == "1"` (You got a typo in your statement, "targetenc")

Comment: I just typed it in at run time. I tried all the _approaches_ that I have shown

Answer (score 1):

When you include an Ansible task file it will attach the `when:` condition to all included tasks. This means that you will see the tasks displayed even when the `when:` condition is false though all tasks will be skipped.

One problem with your code above is `targetenv.stdout`, here is a working version with proper formatting:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    - name: targetenv
      prompt: 1.)EPC 2.)CLIENTS 3)TESTERS
      private: False
      default: "1"

  tasks:
    - name: Inlude playbook tikitaka3a
      include: roles/test/tasks/tikitaka3a.yml target=umar
      when: targetenv|int < 2
```

Comment: Still includes the playbook even when I enter 2 or 3 upon playbook execution

Comment: Updated to mention that your task file will be included, but all tasks will be skipped.